# Footer will not fix with sidebar

Tags: php, css, wordpress, search-box

My theme footer will not appearance when i use sidebar! i tried many ways with css but couldn't fix this issue. here is image of when i use sidebar : http://prntscr.com/4nuf83

And here is there when i'm not use of sidebar : http://prntscr.com/4nufr2

This is my `Footer.php` code :

```
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </footer>
</div><!-- .container -->

</div><!-- span12 -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here you go @xd6 , this is `sidebar` :

```
<div class="sidebar>"
            <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <!-- Blog Search Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Blog Search</h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.input-group -->
                </div>

                <!-- Side Widget Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Side Widget Well</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perspiciatis adipisci accusamus laudantium odit aliquam repellat tempore quos aspernatur vero.</p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

</div><!--end sidebar-->
```

Can you tell me whats the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Not without seeing sidebar.php

Comment: I added sidebar code too.

Comment: Looks like an extra <\div> in there

Comment: Remove 
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

Comment: I deleted <!-- /.row --> , BTW still not work! :\

Comment: Remove the `</div>` aswell that was above it, as @kums said.

Comment: I did. nothing happened.

Comment: <?php get_search_form(); ?> is it printing something?

Comment: @kums is print search box.

Comment: Where does the </button> </span> things begin?

Comment: This was a search form by Html so because i no wanted to change the css graphic just i replace dynamic search box with all html codes inside that DIV.

Comment: I don't see that sidebar code in your site, could you please add it so we can see the issue in context?

Comment: Is not include mainpage! look it at post or page,  http://robertnicjoo.esy.es/uncategorized/hello-world/

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div class="row"></div>` before `<div class="col-lg-n"></div>`

If you miss row it will be floating or hide from indexed element